# Reinforcement learning with function approximation and eligibility traces

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm currently thinking of doing TD(λ) for a DQN network.  I know how to implement if it's a table (you update Q(s,a) and e(s,a) for all state and action pairs), but what happens when the Q value is now retrieved from a function approximator (neural network)?  How would I update for all states as well as do the increments and decay for eligibility traces?

I've found 2 papers that might be related, but they don't really explain how to implement, rather showing the results only.
[PDF Link 1](https://www.elen.ucl.ac.be/Proceedings/esann/esannpdf/es2007-49.pdf)
[PDF Link 2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.05495.pdf)